# PHP Code with broken syntax works, when I rewrite it properly it breaks

Tags: php, contact-form

I'm new to PHP and as a web developer have only been using it to write simple contact forms. Recently I was making a contact form with a file upload feature, not knowing any PHP I found a solution online [here](https://codeconia.com/2021/05/28/html-form-to-email-with-attachment-using-php/). I like it quite a bit because it sends an email from the domain to a personal gmail, which wasn't possible with my old PHP code. I tried to change it up a bit so the $message formatting looks a bit better and so I can use it as a contact form WITHOUT file upload. This is what I got:

```php
    <?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['tel'];
    $subj = $_POST['subject'];
    $usermessage = $_POST['message'];
    
    // $message ="Name = ". $name . "\r\n  Email = ". $email . "\r\n  Phone = ". $phone . "\r\n Message = ". $usermessage; ------- original $message code with what looks like broken syntax

    // new $message code that does not work
    $message = "Name: ".$name. "\r\n";
    $message .= "Email: ".$email. "\r\n";
    $message .= "Phone: ".$phone. "\r\n";
    $message .= "Message: ".$usermessage. "\r\n";
    
    $subject = $subj;
    $fromname ="Someone";
    $fromemail = 'info@domain.com'; 
    $mailto = 'personalemail@gmail.com'; 

    // $content = file_get_contents($fileName);
    // $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());
    // carriage return type (RFC)
    $eol = "\r\n";
    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;
    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;
    // attachment

    // $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    // $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filenameee . "\"" . $eol;
    // $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    // $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
    // $body .= $content . $eol;
    // $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

    //SEND Mail
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // do what you want after sending the email
        header('Location: success.html');
        
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
        print_r( error_get_last() );
    }
```

Basically I just commented out what looked like code for the file, so it wouldn't send a 'noname' attachment with no file extension. That worked, but the formatting had some weird indentations, random text color changes to a a:visited blue/purple, and the = wasn't visually appealing, I'd rather have a ':'. Plus, the syntax looked broken with quotations in the wrong place. So I made the new message code that can be clearly seen, and commented out the original broken one line $message code, and now the email sends with no content. How is this possible? How do I fix this code?

It seems the slightest thing breaks the code to where a message sends completely empty or only one field sends. Commenting a line out, replacing the '=' with ':' in the original $message code, deleting comments, all could possibly break this again.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```php
    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $body .= $eol;  // This line added!
    $body .= $message . $eol;
```